# Calling a procedure that has a refcursor as out parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I created a package as follows :

```
create or replace package apps.xx_sal
as
   PROCEDURE SAL_HIST_C(p_person_id IN NUMBER
                        ,p_success   OUT VARCHAR2
                        ,p_sql   OUT VARCHAR2
                        ,p_cur   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
      l_success            VARCHAR2(32000) := 'OK';
      l_sql                VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_sql_empty          VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_step               VARCHAR2(1000);
      l_query_length       PLS_INTEGER := 0;
      c_process   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := 'SAL_HIST_C';
   BEGIN
      l_step := c_process || ' :: BUILD EMPTY SQL';
      --

      l_sql_empty := ' SELECT person_id
  ,pay_basis_id
  ,change_date

       from apps.salary_hist_v
         WHERE 1 = 2 ';
      --

      --
      l_step := c_process || ' :: BUILD SQL';
      --
      l_sql      :=
         '
    SELECT paf.person_id
          ,paf.pay_basis_id
          ,ppp.change_date change_date

    FROM hr.per_pay_proposals ppp
        ,per_all_assignments_f paf

    WHERE paf.primary_flag = ''Y''

    AND   ppb.pay_basis_id = paf.pay_basis_id
    AND   paf.person_id = :l_person_id ';

      --
      -- check sql query
      l_query_length := LENGTH(l_sql);
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Length of EXECUTED SQL := ' || l_query_length);

      -- open cursor with bind variables applied
      --
      l_step := c_process || ' :: OPEN CURSOR with BIND VARIABLE APPLIED';

      --
      OPEN p_cur FOR l_sql USING p_person_id;

      l_success := 'OK';
      p_sql := l_sql;
      p_success := l_success;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         l_success := 'ERROR :: ' || l_step || CHR(10) || SQLERRM || CHR(10) || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace;
         p_sql := l_sql;
         p_success := l_success;

         OPEN p_cur FOR l_sql_empty;
   END SAL_HIST_C;
```

Now when I am passing the parameter to see the output an error occurs:

```
DECLARE 
 --l_person_id  number;

     l_success            VARCHAR2(32000) ;
      l_sql                VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_cur sys_refcursor;

BEGIN 

  APPS.xx_sal.SAL_HIST_C (   
   person_id=>4816, 
p_success => l_success, 
p_sql=>l_sql,
p_cur => :l_cur);

  COMMIT; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Output Returned from Proc :: ' || l_success); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Executed for the GRID :: ' || l_cur); 
END;
```

Error:

> [Error] Execution (10: 3): ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SAL_HIST_C'
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 18, column 23:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
>   ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I don't know why is the error happens. I am executing in Toad. I think I am not calling the procedure in the anonymous block correctly

Answer (score 0):

@user3809240

There are two ORA errors in your message.

**1. PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SAL_HIST_C'**

Replace

```
APPS.xx_sal.SAL_HIST_C (person_id=>4816, p_success => l_success, p_sql=>l_sql,p_cur => :l_cur);
```

with

```
APPS.xx_sal.SAL_HIST_C (4816,  l_success, l_sql,l_cur);
```

**2. PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'**

We cannot do a console output of refcursor. Comment out the below line and then re-run your caller program.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Executed for the GRID :: ' || l_cur);
```

Now, it should work perfectly.

Cheers,

Madhu.

PS : Please mark this post as ANSWER if my solution works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can see wrong:

1. Your stored procedure has a parameter named `p_person_id`, but you are calling it with a parameter named `person_id` instead.
2. You cannot concatenate a string and a ref cursor.  If you want to display the values that came out of the ref cursor, you will have to repeatedly fetch values from the cursor, displaying each row, until there aren't any left.

Incidentally I don't see the point of the `COMMIT`, as there's no data you're inserting, updating or deleting.